# How to test whether Siren(https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren) moves properly on my app

Tags: ios, swift

i have an app on App Store but it still doesn't have a new version.

I added this library called "Siren" so that i could push a notification to the user that the user could update their app's version.

Because there are no any new version, i can't test whether succeeded in adding "Siren" to my app.

I think this problem may occur in other libraries like iVersion or Harpy too.

Does anyone has a good idea to test this push notification?

Comment: i know that i should just update my apps version but i can't do that now, so i want to know another way to solve it. thanks for your regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, there was a test AppleID　to know whether Siren is added to the project or not.

376771144

↑this is it

thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

The project readme now has some guidance on how to [Test Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren#testing-siren)

> Temporarily change the version string in Xcode (within the .xcodeproj) 
>       to an older version than the one that's currently available in the App 
>       Store. Afterwards, build and run your app, and you should see the alert.
>   If you currently don't have an app in the store, change your bundleID 
>       to one that is already in the store. In the sample app packaged with 
>       this library, we use the iTunes Connect Mobile app's bundleID: 
>       com.apple.itunesconnect.mobile.
>   For your convenience, you may turn on debugging statements by setting 
>       self.debugEnabled = true before calling the checkVersion() method.